# Did you see how fast he move or moved?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, error

Which one is correct

Did you see how fast he move?
Or
Did you see how fast he moved?

Comment: Ali, I will be kind here to you. What happens to the third person singular in the present tense in English? Also, we don't correct sentences. You need to show that you made an effort.

Comment: Please use the "Edit" button to tell more about this question. Why are you wondering about these two tenses? What do you already know about sentences like this one?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see how fast he moved? is correct.

In English grammar, verbs need to conjugate (change their form) to reflect the time of the action. Since the action of moving happened in the past, we need to use the past tense form "moved."

Comment: Much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I don't have any reputation yet to comment, just pointing out that "moves" is another possible construct.

"Did you see how fast he moves?" refers to that which just happened, (hence the use of "Did"), but having "moves" turns what just happened into an example of his *current* capability.